# How can I deploy my Vite- React and Typescript app to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, heroku, deployment, vite

I'm struggling to deploy my front end vite app to heroku as it seems to be looking for a start script and vite doesn't really have one.

These are logs I'm getting:

```
2022-08-23T23:34:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-23T23:34:35.042812+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-23T23:34:36.672295+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2022-08-23T23:34:36.690924+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691243+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691273+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691308+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691345+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-08-23T23:34:36.691382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-08-23T23:34:36.692657+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-23T23:34:36.692823+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-08-23T23:34:36.692964+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-08-23T23_34_36_639Z-debug-0.log
2022-08-23T23:34:36.822926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-23T23:34:36.901286+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

and that's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "JJ app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "vite": "^3.0.7",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.2",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "eslint-config-react-typescript": "^1.0.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "w3-css": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

How should I setup my scripts to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Create a special file at project root named `Procfile` and put inside the following content:

```
web: vite preview --port $PORT
```

I don’t have experience with Heroku. I know because it is documented in Heroku help center

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs?singlepage=true
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

And of course you need to know a little bit about `vite preview` command.

- https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#testing-the-app-locally

Above links are reachable by searching “heroku deploy node” and “vite deploy”. Hopefully sharing my process would help you learn how to unstuck yourself next time. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much. After a long time searching it's finally working (2023)!